# GitLab new project setup webhook

Tags: project, gitlab, webhooks

I have GitLab setup on a server. Every time I create a new project under my user, I have to manually add a Web Hook by navigating to `Project -> Settings -> Web Hooks -> Add Web Hook`

Since many users will be creating projects on the hosted GitLab it will be difficult to setup Web Hooks for each project individually.

Is there a way, so that when a new project is created, it automatically (as default) sets up a Web Hook as part of the new project?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could probably find a way to automate this via the [System Hooks API](http://api.gitlab.org/system_hooks.html). Listen for the `project_create` hook event, then make a call to the [project hook endpoint](http://api.gitlab.org/projects.html#add-project-hook) to add the one you want.

It's webhooks all the way down!

Comment: @KunalAggarwal Can you provide an example how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this script what do all you need:

recive the hook and execute the query insert of web hook

Run with php -S 0.0.0.0:8080

```
  <?php
  $allowed_host = "ip_of_your_gitlab_server";
  $sql_host = "localhost_or_ip_of_your_mysql_server";
  $sql_user = "..";
  $sql_password = "..";
  $database = "gitlabhq_production";

  if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $allowed_host) { // ofc you could increase security with some kind of API key or w/e
      $sql = mysqli_connect($sql_host, $sql_user, $sql_password, $database);
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          exit;
      }
      $file = fopen("/tmp/sql_error", "a"); // you can use this as debug log too ;)

      $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
      $pid = $input['project_id'];

      if ($input['event_name'] == "project_create") {
          $url = 'url_of_your_project_hook';
          // this creates a project hook, specify it for your needs..
          $q = mysqli_query($sql, "INSERT INTO gitlabhq_production.web_hooks (url, project_id) VALUES('$url', '$pid')");

          if (!$q) fwrite($file, $sql->error);
      } elseif ($input['event_name'] == "project_destroy")
          $q = mysqli_query($sql, "DELETE FROM gitlabhq_production.web_hooks WHERE project_id='$pid'");

      mysqli_close($sql);
  } else {
      // redirect?
      exit;
  }
```